# Eclipse: Limit resource and type searches to just the open project?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2 on Windows 7 Professional.

I use ctrl + shift + t and ctrl + shift + r a lot to quickly find my files.

Only problem is I have two projects with many of the same filenames and the dialog box that comes up lists all matching file name from all projects in the workspace.

Is there a setting somewhere where I can tell eclipse to only find files in the currently selected project?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the general search feature, as follows:

1. Left-click your current project in Project Explorer view.
2. Select Search | Search menu item (mapped to Ctrl-H on my installation).
3. There are various tabs for different types of search, e.g. Java Search will let you find Java classes (which of course map to filename prefixes).
4. The Scope group-box at the bottom of the search window allows you to restrict the scope to current project.

Note: there is a bug in Eclipse (your version, and possibly later ones, too) where the 'Project' scope radio-button can be disabled/unselectable, but fortunately a workaround exists. Close the search window, left-click any item NOT in your current project, then left-click an item in your current project, then reopen the search window. The 'Project' scope radio-button should now be selectable.